# Editing the css of class "thing" when hovering over class "bn1", "bn2", "bn3" and so on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

Sort of like this

[image: http://puu.sh/gnWrD/a9e22a013f.png]

When I hover my mouse over the first "projekter-btn", the preview-p should change. Then when i hover over the second and third btn, the preview-p should then change accordingly. I'm trying to do this in jQuery without repeating myself a ton of times.

Comment: Please post your code rather than a screenshot

Comment: CSS selectors cannot climb up the html tree, it only goes down, so you need javascript :) . Some tricky solution could be used but no code , no chocolate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sy7gpbt7/). Assuming what you want to do is add a class to preview-p. What I did is just add the class you want to add using a new attribute on each projekter-btn. Hope this helps!

```
$(".p-btn").hover(function() {
    var classToAdd = $(this).attr('data-preview-class');
    $(".p-preview").removeClass().addClass("p-preview"); //this resets the classes
    $(".p-preview").addClass(classToAdd);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is very basic, I hope this clears your doubt:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".projekter-btn").on("mouseenter", function() {

    $(".preview-p").css("color", $(this).attr("addcolor"));

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="projekter-btn"></div>
  <div class="projekter-btn" addcolor="green">a</div>
  <div class="projekter-btn" addcolor="red">a</div>
  <div class="projekter-btn" addcolor="blue">a</div>
  <div class="projekter-btn" addcolor="yellow">a</div>
</div>

<div class="preview">
  <div class="preview-p">sdadassa</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha, but not like that. That means when I hover over ANY over the projekter-btn the preview changes to the same (say it changes to red whenever I hover over ANY of the projekter-btn). I need it to change based on which projekter-btn i'm hovering on, so if I'm hovering above the first one it changes to.. idunno, blue. Then I hover over the second btn and it changes to red.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. However; if i'm understanding, maybe this will help. This would simply put whatever is in div.projekter-btn and put it into preview-p, i didn't not include the out hover part of .hover(). I hope this helps.

```
something like...

<script>
// jQuery document on load

$( "div.projekter-btn" ).hover(function() {
$( this ).appendTo( ".preview-p" );
});

</script>
```

/****Sorry quick edit. ****/ THIS**